# 12.10 error upon bootup and upgrade

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, dpkg

I upgraded to 12.10 in my quest to get to 14.04, but my computer (HP Pavilion dv 6c47cl) doesn't seem to like 12.10. It won't load to the gui, and so I am forced to go to the command line if I want to load ubuntu at all (and it still won't go to command line with startx).

I have tried upgrading from command line with the following commands:

1) `sudo do-release-upgrade`

(reports no new release found)

2) `sudo apt-get update`

```
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

(this will start trying, but will ultimately fail because it encountered an error while processing, was unable to open a file, or some other reason)
Now whenever I run

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

I get

```
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.13.3-0ubuntu6.2_all.deb (--unpack): trying to overwrite '/var/lib/xkb/README.compiled', which is also in package xserver-common-lts-raring 2:1.13.3-0ubuntu6~precise3

No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already

Errors were encountered while processing: /var/cache/apt/archives/xserver-common_2%3a1.13.3-0ubuntu6.2_all.deb

E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any advice on things I can try to make the upgrade happen?

Comment: try `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands,

```
sudo apt-get purge xserver-common-lts-raring
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Now run any of your commands like `sudo apt-get upgrade` or `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the issue myself:

1. `sudo apt-get remove xserver-common-lts-raring`
2. If needed enter your password.
3. When asked to remove type yes.

That should remove the file, and then you should have no more issues.

That worked the first time I tried it.